# python pandas calculate number of days based on Date column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns - 'Route Name' and 'Date'. The route name contains names of various cities and 'Date' represents events recorded in those cities.

For example, the filtered df for London is as below =>

```
Route Name       Date
London           2019-10-09
London           2019-10-09
London           2019-10-10
London           2019-10-10
London           2019-10-11
London           2019-10-11
London           2019-10-11
London           2019-10-11
London           2019-10-12
London           2019-10-12
London           2019-10-12
```

How can I get the number of days per city?. Expected answer would be something like

```
Route Name   Frequency(days)
London       4
Manchester   5
Glasgow      5
```

etc..

Comment: `df.groupby('Route Name').Date.nunique()`.

Comment: Nice.. this gives count of total dates. Can this be further bifurcated to show count per month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from Quang Hoang's comment, and modified to include your question about count per month:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


string = """Route Name\tDate
London\t2019-10-09
London\t2019-10-09
London\t2019-10-10
London\t2019-10-10
London\t2019-10-11
London\t2019-10-11
London\t2019-10-11
London\t2019-10-11
London\t2019-10-12
London\t2019-10-12
London\t2019-10-12
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), sep = "\t")
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
print(df.head())
"""
  Route Name       Date
0     London 2019-10-09
1     London 2019-10-09
2     London 2019-10-10
3     London 2019-10-10
4     London 2019-10-11
"""

df["Year"] = df["Date"].dt.year
df["Month"] = df["Date"].dt.month
print(df.head())
"""
  Route Name       Date  Year  Month
0     London 2019-10-09  2019     10
1     London 2019-10-09  2019     10
2     London 2019-10-10  2019     10
3     London 2019-10-10  2019     10
4     London 2019-10-11  2019     10
"""

annual_df = df.groupby(["Route Name", "Year"])["Date"].nunique()
print(annual_df.head())
"""
Route Name  Year
London      2019    4
Name: Date, dtype: int64
"""

monthly_df = df.groupby(["Route Name", "Year", "Month"])["Date"].nunique()
print(monthly_df.head())
"""
Route Name  Year  Month
London      2019  10       4
Name: Date, dtype: int64
"""
```